# how to set SimpleDateFormat "W" use the MONDAY is first day of Week?

Tags: java

SimpleDateFormat "W" default set SUNDAY is first day of week,ex:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("W"); 
format.f(new Date());
```

i want to set "W" first day is MONDAY,i try:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("W"); 
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTimeInMillis(input); 
c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY); 
format.format(c.getTime())
```

but no effect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use setCalendar() on your SimpleDateFormat to set the calendar used for date calculations:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("W");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek( Calendar.MONDAY );
format.setCalendar( calendar ); 
format.format( whateverDateYouWantToFormat );`
```