# Sort by day of the week from Monday to Sunday in Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have day in below format.

```
"Fri 05:00"
"Tue 10:15"
"Mon 02:00"
```

And I want to sort this day which is starting from Monday to Sunday.

I have tried with formatting this dates to

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE hh:mm");
```

Then I have created List of these dates. Then I have used Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK in Comparator but it is sorted from dates which is starting from Sunday not Monday.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429998/how-to-sort-strings-containing-day-of-week-names-in-ascending-order
answers your question?

Comment: No. It is sorting from Sunday to Saturday and not from Monday to Sunday.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1353809/1638059) to set monday as the first day of the week.

Comment: Once you have the day of week `d` (1 to 7) you could sort by the value `(d + 5) % 7`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sebastian. But it didn't work.

Comment: @Henry. Thanks for suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: How do you try it? Share your code.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: You should construct a list of objects from the strings and then use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` to use your own Comparator to compare those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Define a class

There is no class bundled with Java to represent a day-of-week combined with a time-of-day. The bundled class would require a date.

You will need to define your own such class, perhaps named `DayOfWeekWithTime`. That class will have two member fields, a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) object and a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) object. Search Stack Overflow for many existing posts on these classes.

```
public class DayOfWeekWithTime {
    // Member fields
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeek ;
    LocalTime localTime ;

    // Constructor
    public DayOfWeekWithTime ( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek , LocalTime localTime ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( dayOfWeek ) ;
        Objects.requireNonNull( localTime ) ;
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek ;
        this.localTime = localTime ;
    }
}
```

The `DayOfWeek` enum follows the ISO 8601 standard, so the week is defined as Monday-Sunday. This matches your desired sort order. So you can sort a collection of `DayOfWeekWithTime` objects by that member field. See [`Collections.sort( list , comparator )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)). Search Stack Overflow for many existing posts on the topic of sorting objects by a particular field.

To instantiate your `DayOfWeekWithTime` objects from string inputs as seen in the Question, split on the SPACE character. See [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). Search Stack Overflow for many existing posts on the topic of splitting strings.

Then write a routine to lookup a `DayOfWeek` enum for each of your 3-letter input values. You could write a `if-else-if` series. Or you could write a `Map< String , DayOfWeek >`.

For the time-of-day, you can parse using `LocalTime.parse` method. If using 24-hour clock with padding zero on single digits, you need not define a formatting pattern as the *java.time* classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text.   Search Stack Overflow for many existing posts on the topic of parsing with the *java.time* classes.

Do *not* use `SimpleDateFormat` or the related terrible date-time classes that are now legacy, such as `Date` or `Calendar`. Use only *java.time* classes for date-time work.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with creating new classes but this is very useful with new Java features.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar has the method

```
setFirstDayOfWeek(ind day)
```

You can use it: `calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.Monday)`

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).